# Rails: redirect_to:back not redirecting in spite of showing correct logs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, coffeescript

**My html**

```
<div class="modal-body center">         
      <form method="post">
        <textarea ng-model = "post.review" rows="10" cols="50" name="review" placeholder="something thougtful and helpful" style = "color: red;" class="fsField fsRequired fsTextAreaMaxLength", maxlength = "116"></textarea>

        <input ng-model = "post.rating" type="integer" name="rating" placeholder="0-10" style="color: red;" class="fsField fsRequired fsTextAreaMaxLength", maxlength = "116">

        <button ng-click = "submitReview(product)" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>

      <div ng-show = "duplicate_status" class = "submitStatus">*You have already submitted review for this Product</div>
      <div ng-show = "success_status" class = "submitStatus">*Your Review is successfully submitted</div>    
 </div>
```

**My javascript**

```
$scope.submitReview = (product)->
  $scope.review =
    'review': $scope.post.review
    'rating': $scope.post.rating
    'product_id': product.id

  $http.post("/products/#{product.id}/review/new",$scope.review).success((data) ->
    if data == 'duplicate'
      $scope.duplicate_status = true

    if data == 'success'
      $scope.success_status = true    
)
```

**rails controller**

```
def create
  if !current_user.present?
    redirect_to :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'create'
    return
  end
  if Review.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :product_id => params[:product_id]).first.present?      
   render plain: "duplicate"    
  end
  @review = Review.new(:review => params[:review],
                     :rating => params[:rating],
                     :product_id => params[:product_id],
                     :user_id => current_user.id,
                     :date => Time.now.to_date)   
  if @review.save        
    redirect_to :back             
  else
    redirect_to :back        
  end    
end
```

The problem is that on successful operation the i.e., on `@review.save` the `redirect_to :back` doesn't refresh the page.
This is in spite of the logs being shown correctly.

**logs**

```
Started POST "/products/2/review/new" for 192.168.1.88 at 2015-05-26 16:27:37 +0530
Processing by ReviewsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"review"=>"Test Review", "rating"=>"1", "product_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  Review Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews"  WHERE "reviews"."user_id" = 3 AND "reviews"."product_id" = 2  ORDER BY "reviews"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "reviews" ("created_at", "date", "product_id", "rating", "review", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-05-26 10:57:37.245018"], ["date", "2015-05-26"], ["product_id", 2], ["rating", 1.0], ["review", "Test Review"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-26 10:57:37.245018"], ["user_id", 3]]
   (13.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://192.168.1.88:7001/product/2
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)


Started GET "/product/2" for 192.168.1.88 at 2015-05-26 16:27:37 +0530


Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.88 at 2015-05-26 16:27:37 +0530
Processing by HomeController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_invite_modal.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_confirm_modal.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (10.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb (40.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 42.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

The problem is that control gets unnecessarily transferred to `GET "/"`

Am I missing a trick with `return` somewhere ?

Comment: The page won't refresh because you are using javascript to post the review, hence you need to return some response to show successful operation as opposed to using redirect call.

Comment: @ usmanali : I tried doing that , I did `render plain: "success"` instead of `redirect_to :back` and in javascript in did `$http.get("/product/#{product.id}")` on check of `if data == 'success'`. But did not seem to work

Comment: how about using `json` response? Something like `render json: {success: true }`

Comment: Tried with `json` as well right now. Didn't show any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your are redirecting only the XHR request made by javascript -- the page shown to the user remains unaffected.

To look at this in more detail, when your form is submitted, you trigger some code. This code makes an HTTP post to the server. The server does stuff, then redirects **that** request. Your javascript follows that redirect behind the scenes, and loads the new page. All of this is happening hidden from the user, only affecting the HTTP request that javascript fired off, not the main page itself.

In order to make the main page window change, you'll have to explicitly tell the page go somewhere else using window.location.

For example:

```
$http.post("/products/#{product.id}/review/new",$scope.review).success((data) ->
    ...
    window.location = data.redirect_url
```

And in the controller:

```
render :json, {status: "duplicate", redirect_url: "/product/2"}
```